# Continuous function has vanishing limit.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, continuity

If $f$ were a continuous function such that it vanished when $x$ tended to either $\pm\infty$, then prove that $$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |f(x)||1-e^{2\pi iyx}| \rightarrow0,$$ as $y \rightarrow 0$. Now I can easily show (through a geometric argument) that we can bound $|1-e^{2\pi i yx}|$ by $2 \pi |yx|$. We also have the plain $2$ bound by triangle inequality. But how can I use this to conclude the above? For any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ $|f(x)||1-e^{2 \pi i yx}| \leq 2 \pi |f(x)||yx|$ for sufficiently small $y$. Also I can choose $|f(x)| < \epsilon$ whenever $|x| \geq N$, but I am nnot sure if this would be in the right direction. Any help is welcmed.

Comment: Just show that $f$ is bounded. It follows from vanishing of $f$ as $x$ goes to $\pm\infty$.

Comment: @OğuzhanKılıç: Thank you for your comment. This puts me here: $|f(x)||1-e^{2 \pi i yx}| \leq M |1-e^{2 \pi i yx}|$ from here I would need a bound that does not depend on $x$ to take the supremum and prove the limit correct?

Answer (score 1):

Based off of the comment OğuzhanKılıç left, we know that $|f(x)| \leq M$ for some $M \in \mathbb{R}^+$. Then another piece of useful information you have is that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $e^{2 \pi iyx} \rightarrow 1$ as $y \rightarrow 0$. Therefore for sufficiently small, say  $|y| < \delta$ you have $|1-e^{2\pi iyx}| < \epsilon$. Combining these should give the result you are looking for.